# Using CAST encryption in a C# Metro/WinRT app

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, cryptography, microsoft-metro

Is there a .NET API that supports CAST encryption for Metro/WinRT?  Something equivalent to this CommonCrypto call on iOS:

```
CCCrypt((mode == KeyEncryptionDecrypt) ? kCCDecrypt : kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmCAST, 0,
          keyBuff, keySize,
          initVector,
          decryptData, decryptSize,
          buffer, bufferSize,
          dataOutSize);
```

From reading through the docs for the Windows 8 [SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.symmetrickeyalgorithmprovider%28v=win.10%29.aspx) I don't see support for CAST.  I investigated using OpenSSL (I can call C++ from my C# Metro app), but the OpenSSL library makes some desktop API calls from its randomization functions and so it wouldn't link under Metro.  Is there a way to use CAST encryption from my C# Metro app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [BouncyCastle for C#](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/). Check the feature list.

There is a WinRT-compatible version of BouncyCastle [here](http://w8bouncycastle.codeplex.com/), link provided by dbeachy1.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I found a WinRT-compatible version of BouncyCastle [here](http://w8bouncycastle.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Can you see what is different from the normal C# code & build? It's rather badly documented (read, it's not really documented).

Comment: A quick scan showed a rather intact BC and a few helper classes to do with asymmetric key generation (you may want to scan over those). Furthermore it contains gzip support, copied from Apache licensed code - not MIT. Otherwise it is just contains the necessary files to aid building the lib for WinRT.